# List Specifically Selected app From Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I know a way for this question for only one app

```
String desiredAppId = "com.rovio.angrybirds";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id="+desiredAppId));
startActivity(i);
```

But if i want to list all *(free && selected developer && release date>2011 && etc)* how can implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if i want to list all (free && selected developer && date>2011 && etc) how can implement it?

You cannot create arbitrary queries. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html) outlines the limited options: a single app, all apps for a developer, or the results of a keyword search. There is no "date" and there is no "&&".

Comment: Can't i get these values with XML if Google Play support it?

Comment: @hakiko: I have no idea what your previous comment means. Note that there are many Android developer support sites available, in a variety of languages -- I have some listed at http://andglobe.com.